# European characters switch to strange characters in response when posting to server using C++

Tags: c++, node.js, utf-8, libcurl, asio

I am struggeling to get the response from the server in correct format under Windows. I have tried two C++ libraries Beast, (based on Boost Asio) and Cpr (based on libcurl) and I get the exact same issue with both.

The strange thing is that I also tried this in C# (HttpClient) and everything works just fine. Also, in Postman and other REST tools it looks good.

When I post to the server and should get back the name René I get Renï¿½ instead. Other European characters like æ,ø,å,ö give the same strange output. To me it looks like an issue with utf-8 / iso-8859-1 but I cannot figure it out. The server (based on node.js) and the response is set to push out utf-8. We have tried to just redirect the response so it does not hit a database or anything like that. So, the problem is under C++ it seems. Any suggestions to what I can try would be greatly appreciated.

Example code:

```
nlohmann::json test_json = nlohmann::json
{
    { "text", "Hi, my name is René" },
    { "language", "en" }
};

auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{ "http://www.exampleserver.com" },
    cpr::Body{ test_json.dump() },
    cpr::Header{ { "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" } });

std::cout << r.text << std::endl;
```

Comment: Look at the raw bytes of what you're submitting to make *sure* you're doing it as UTF-8. "René" should be `82, 101, 110, 195, 169`.

Comment: Well, acutally I am postin 82, 101, 110, -23. The negative last number I thought had to do with some ascii stuff that didnt fit into the regular ascii set ?

Comment: What are they as *unsigned* chars? There's no character -23. That's presumably 231, but that's a ç character in ISO-8859-1. What I find especially odd is you have a single é turning into three characters. Usually UTF-8 mistakes manifest as two with a single mis-encoding, or four if doubly messed up.

Comment: I get it unsigned at 233.

Comment: That's ISO-8859-1 for `é` so you're not using UTF-8 like you think you are. I usually check the [character charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) when trying to get to the bottom of these encoding issues.

Comment: Hmmm? So, I am posting iso-8859-1 to the server, but I am telling it that it is utf-8 by setting "content-type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" ?

Comment: If you do that then the string will get mangled because it's going to be invalid UTF-8. You need to encode it properly or identify the content type properly.

Comment: So, how it basically works is that I need to convert the string to utf-8 first before posting and then I am telling the server that the string you get is utf-8 by content-type. I am used to .NETwhere it is a lot of stuff is happening behind the scenes. I guess that the string there is converted automagically. So, I was expecting something like that happing here too :) Going to give it a try imediately!

Comment: If you can get it to go UTF-8 all the way through then that's usually the best. If you can't, at least identify the payload type correctly. The trouble with text is there's no built-in way of specifying that, every text-based protocol does it differently.

Comment: Now, it works!! I was able to convert to and from with the boost libraries. Thank you so much!! @tadman if you like you can add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some ISO-8859-1 content being sent through but it's labelled as UTF-8. This causes a whole rash of conversion errors which can mangle non-ASCII characters beyond recognition.

The way to fix this is to either identify the non-UTF-8 data and properly convert it, or identify the payload with the correct MIME type and encoding.

Comment: Excellent!! Unfortunatle I cannot upvote this as I do not have the reputation yet... I was able to fix this issue by converting back and forth to utf from iso-8859-1 by using the libraries from Boost. std::string output = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>("René", "ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the encoded string. The string is most likely coming back UTF-8 encoded but you are not converting it properly.

There are various libraries that help you convert. It all depends on the version of C++ you're using. Hard to tell you what to use without more details.

Comment: It is very simple. Here is the Cpr example. I am getting a std::string from the response:.